# WIndows Service in c#

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, service, tcp

Im working on a project in which requirement is such that I need to read HKLM settings from a XML file and write those settings into the windows registry. I need advice on what is the best option of the following for this purpose:

1. Windows Service running on Network layer
2. WCF service with TCP protocol
3. Named Pipes

As the user logged into the system will not be having enough privileges to run the service, therefore there need to be provided higher privileges to the service at the time of installation so that service is able to run and write the settings in HKLM.

The XML with reg settings will be generated by another application. After generating the XML file the application will call the proposed service to write the reg settings in the windows registry. As the application which originally generates the XML file runs with less privileged credentials (non admin), so it cannot write the HKLM settings in registry. Therefore I need a service running with a higher level of privileges separately from the Application. When the application has generated the XML file, it will communicate to the service and the proposed service will read that XML file and create reg settings.

There will be no user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the requirements on : when do you want to read XML file for HKLM settings, is an user interaction needed?
Is it based on some user action? Or is it a scheduled job?
If it's scheduled and requiring no interaction, go for a Windows Service
otherwise WCF service.

It's just that the hosting mechanisms are different.
Note that WCF Service can still be hosted as a Windows Service as well as Windows Service can also setup HTTP listener(s) on a port(s)

Regarding privileges, both hosting mechanism will need. It's actually recommended to use Service Accounts with proper permissions.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Go for a WCF service hosted in IIS for now. In future, it can still be hosted as Windows service with some code extensions. I'll also suggest to separate the hosting part from biz\features implementation